# Make bootstrap work for Angular project?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, wakanda

I am setting up my dev environment on Windows with Wakanda for the first time.

I have `npm install`ed `--save` bootstrap4 and jquery.

My page is not taking on bootstrap class styles.

Below is my code for package.json (i started with unix filesystem '/' characters and tried windows '\', neither worked)

Do I need to modify index.html?

```
  "scripts": [
    "..\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js",
    "..\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js"
  ],
  "styles": [
    "..\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ]
```

Comment: That's the correct way. I don't know if it matters but you have backslashes in the path, try changing all slashes to /

Comment: that was a good suggestion. i tried it and it did not work. i will edit my question.

Comment: The other way around: Use / slashes (even on Windows), because backslash is the escape character in json.

Comment: hm i switched them back to all unix `/` slashes but still didn't work. i'm really not sure why this isnt working but i might be able to resolve the issue by referencing the scripts and css files in my index.html and then i feel like that would take care of it

Comment: adding them via `<script>` and `<link>` tags in the index html didn't work actually. im pretty confused

Comment: I wonder if something went wrong with the npm install. Did you check the css file exists in node_modules?

Comment: yeah it's there. it occurred to me that i said "package.json" when i meant to say "angular-cli.json. i wonder if i edited the wrong file like a goof. i'll check later when i am home

Comment: That'd explain a lot :)

Comment: that was definitely it. thanks for helping me along haha.

Answer (score 2):

I was editing the wrong file. I was editing `package.json` in Wakanda's `backend` directory. I should have been editing `angular-cli.json`.